# How do I store stored function call with arguments and retrieve them later for callback in C++?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, callback, task

What I am trying to do now is to store stored function calls with arguments into a list or vector, retrieve them later, and call them.

What I've got now:

a task class:

```
struct basic_task
{
    virtual ~basic_task()
    {
    }
    virtual void run()
    {
        std::cout<<"will run basic"<<std::endl;
    }
};
template<typename OBJ, typename FUNC, typename ...ARGS>
struct task: basic_task
{
    OBJ obj_;
    FUNC OBJ::*func_;
    std::tuple<ARGS...> args_;
    task(OBJ& obj, FUNC OBJ::*func, ARGS ... args) :
            obj_(obj), func_(func)
    {
        args_ = std::make_tuple(std::forward<ARGS>(args)...);
    }
    virtual ~task()
    {
        //delete args_;
    }
    virtual void run()
    {
        std::cout<<"will run real"<<std::endl;
        caller::call(obj_, func_, args_);
    }
};
```

a task binder:

```
struct task_binder
{
    template<typename OBJ, typename FUNC, typename ...ARGS>
    static auto bind(OBJ& obj, FUNC OBJ::*func,
            ARGS ... args)->task<OBJ,FUNC,ARGS...>
    {
        task<OBJ, FUNC, ARGS...> result
        { obj, func, args... };
        return result;
    }
};
```

And what I am trying to do now is a task_queue class, which stores instances by calling produce, and consume the task by calling consume.

```
class task_queue: public task_queue_if
{
public:
    task_queue() :
            flag_(true), cond_(mutex_)
    {
    }
    virtual ~task_queue()
    {
    }
    virtual void close()
    {
        lock_guard lock(mutex_);
        flag_ = false;
        cond_.broadcast();
    }
    virtual void produce(const basic_task& t)
    {
        lock_guard lock(mutex_);
        bool was_empty = task_list_.empty();
        task_list_.push_back(t);
        if (was_empty)
        {
            cond_.signal();
        }
    }
    virtual int consume()
    {
        lock_guard lock(mutex_);
        while (task_list_.empty())
        {
            if (flag_ == false)
                return -1;
            cond_.wait();
        }
        basic_task tt = task_list_.front();
        task_list_.pop_front();
        tt.run()  // won't call the stored function call    

        return 1;
    }
private:
    volatile bool flag_;
    mutex_lock mutex_;
    std::list<basic_task> task_list_;
    condition_var cond_;
}
```

So my problem is the consume call will call the basic_task's run() function rather than the one in task. However, if I did not store them as type basic_task but as task, it won't compile. And if I store them as basic_task, when I want to call it, I won't know which type of task should I cast the task to, so it won't compile either. Is there a way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Your `task_list_` never stores a `task` object, it slices the argument to `produce` and stores a `basic_task`. Change it to `std::list<std::unique_ptr<basic_task>> task_list_;` and change `produce` to `virtual void produce(std::unique_ptr<basic_task> t)`. Also `volatile` doesn't help with multithreading, `flag_` should most likely be `std::atomic<bool>`

Comment: Could you please demonstrate how to do it with unique_ptr? I get the idea of using unique_ptr but I could not get unique_ptr to work. Error was `use of deleted function` when `push_back` the `unique_ptr` into a `list`, but I did use `std::move` as I `push_back`. Thank you very much.

Comment: You may use `std::function` to simplify your stuff.